# Validate two fields with express-validator custom validators

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I have two fields: login and password. I use custom validators to validate:

```
login: {
  isNotNull: { errorMessage: 'Required field' },
  isServiceUser: {
    errorMessage: 'Failed to login',
    options: req.body.password,
  },
},
password: {
  isNotEmpty: { errorMessage: 'Required field' },
}
```

isServiceUser validates by making http request to another service. How can I validate them both at once and send to client that both fields are invalid?

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom validation.

**Assume you want to check password if exist and user name:**

```
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check')
app.post(upload.single('customerImage'),[
check('name').custom(async (name, {req}) => {
                // api request for fetching user name
                const res = await getCust(name) 
                // change if condition to make it do what you want
                if(!res && req.body.password === ""){
                     throw new Error('user name or password invalid')
                }
                })], (req, res) => { 
                       const errors = validationResult(req)
                       if(!errors.isEmpty()){
                           return res.status(442).json({ errors: errors.array() })
                       }
                       //do something
                })
```

**You have to change the validation condition as you like.**

If you want to use [Schema Validation](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/schema-validation.html)

Answer (score 1):

It can be implemented this way:

```
body(['login', 'password']).custom((value) => { // your logic here });
```

callback provided to custom method will be called two times for each field (login and password)